# Why doesn't a * in my pipe open in Perl work on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, environment-variables, pipe, wildcard

I am having this strange issue with Perl. I am trying to execute an external program from inside my Perl script and this external program takes string + wildcard as parameters. My Perl program looks like this

```
my $cmd_to_run = 'find-something-in-somedb myname* |' 
open(procHandle, $cmd_to_run); # I am using open because I want to 
                               # parse the output using pipes
```

For some weird reason, running this Perl script (under Windows) call to `open` function ends up with error:

```
'sqlselect' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I guessed that its something to do with `*` present in my command string and hence I removed it and now my command string looks like this

```
my $cmd_to_run = 'find-something-in-somedb myname|'
```

Now when I run my Perl script it works perfectly fine. Problem comes only when wildcard character is present.

Some points to note :

1. I ran the same command with wildcard char, in the same cmd prompt (where i am executing this perl script) and it works perfectly fine..
2. Same command works when I program it in C using _open function in Windows.
3. Problem seems to be only when wildcard * is present , at least that's what I am guessing
4. No, I haven't tried this in Unix..

Any clues???

**EDIT** : I found that this is something to do with ENV . The program that i am trying to run uses "sqlselect" only when "*" wild card is present in search string...
Both find-something-in-somedb and sqlselect are present in same location. In which case how perl is able to find "find-in-db" and not "sqlselect"

Sorry i realize that original problem is turning out to be something else now.. Something to do with "ENV" and not with Wildcard *

Answer (score 6):

It is recommended to use the 3-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

```
open(procHandle, '-|', 'find-something-in-somedb', 'myname*');
```

as that bypasses the shell (which will perform `*` expansion).

However, on Windows, applications often perform their own quote-parsing and `*` expansion, so you may need

```
open(procHandle, '-|', 'find-something-in-somedb', '"myname*"');
```

or even

```
open(procHandle, '-|', 'find-something-in-somedb "myname*"');
```

as I'm not sure exactly how and when Perl hands things off to `cmd`.

Comment: This is something to do with $PATH i guess.. Perl is able to find "find-in-db" but not "sqlselect" when both these are present in same network directory. and this network directory is added to my path variable in my cmd prompt session.

Comment: Figured out that it was stupid case sensitive issue. Damn i can't be more dumb.. The problem is sqlselect is present in same directory but its file name is "SqlSelect" and perl doesn't seem to like this.

Comment: That is very odd, because on Windows, looking for a file named "`sqlselect`" *should* match a file named "`SqlSelect`"... but all's good if you managed to resolve the issue.  I still recommend moving to the 3-arg open: it's a good habit in general.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that Perl is expanding the wildcard itself, which you don't want to do. The answer provided by [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) is very good, but in order to debug this, try calling this really simple program:

```
print join ' ', @ARGV;
```

Put that into its own file, then call it from your original program (I named mine argv.pl):

```
my $cmd_to_run = './argv.pl myname* |' 
open(procHandle, $cmd_to_run);
```

That will definitively tell you on your platform how Perl is parsing things. On Unix, the * is expanded to match the files in the current working directory. Not sure about Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use three-argument `open`?

```
open my $procHandle, '-|', 'find-something-in-somedb myname*'
    or die "Cannot open pipe: $!";
```

Comment: I'll upvote to balance it out, but indeed... downvote and no comment explaining why?

Comment: @ephemient Thank you very much. I understand if my answer is ignored because it is a subset of yours but I was a little surprised to see it actively downvoted (just as I was thinking I should delete it ;-) @James Thompson I think we agree that it is common courtesy to at least tell the person who is trying to help what he is doing wrong. Thank you.